# Is it possible to use the h264 and aac encoders that ship with windows 7 from directshow?

Tags: winapi, video, directshow, ms-media-foundation

I see that windows 7 ships with an [aac encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742785%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and an [h264 encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797816%28VS.85%29.aspx). I'm writing a directshow application that needs to do video encoding. I think: "Great! Now I don't have to license a video encoder!", but then I read on to discover that these encoders use the new MFT api which seems to be incompatible with directshow, and there doesn't seem to be a wrapper filter like there is with DMO. Is there a way for me to use these filters in directshow? Maybe there's a wrapper I didn't find? Maybe I can access these filters as DMO's?

Comment: Looking through the available DirectShow filters with Graphedt on Windows 7, I don't see anything that looks like it makes them available...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the H264 and AAC encoders are only available using the Media Foundation APIs.  See the [Supported Media Formats in Media Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.  So if you want to make use of these you'll need to use WMF instead of or in addition to DirectShow.  As far as I know there is now wrapper or adapter to get a MF graph into DirectShow.

The good news is that MF is much improved compared to DirectShow and offers very nice higher level APIs for video like the [SinkWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff819461%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which make it much easier to write video to a file.